# Why I have error where existing data is checked (python)

Tags: python, excel, tkinter

There is an issue with code, it displays an error about indented block.
Can someone from different point of view check this code? And explain why there is issue with if statement? Maybe also you have some suggestions for current code.

Kind regards,
J.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x700")
ivn = StringVar()
inputVarName = Entry(root, textvariable=str(ivn))
ivn.set(str("text1"))
inputVarName.grid(row=0, column=0)

ivn2 = StringVar()
inputVarName2 = Entry(root, textvariable=str(ivn2))
ivn2.set(str("text2"))
inputVarName2.grid(row=1, column=0)


def printSomething():
    with open('help.txt') as f:
        r = f.read()
    label = Label(root, text=r)
    label.grid()


def checkdata():
    with open('help.txt') as f:
        r = f.read()
    return r.split("\n")


def writetofile():
    exist_data = checkdata()
    content_list = [ivn.get(), ivn2.get()]
    with open("help.txt", "a") as f:
        for item in content_list:
        if item in exist_data:
            msg = "Already exist "+item
            label = Label(root, text=msg)
            label.grid()
        elif not item in exist_data:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)


applyButton = Button(root, text="Add Data", command=writetofile)
applyButton.grid(row=2, column=1)

veiwButton = Button(root, text='View Data', command=printSomething)
veiwButton.grid(row=3, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you need to indent the `if item in exist_data:` line and the things after it

Comment: It is quite obvious that the if/else block should be inside the for loop.  Indent the if/else block one more level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `writetofile()` function to this:

```
def writetofile():
    exist_data = checkdata()
    content_list = [ivn.get(), ivn2.get()]
    with open("help.txt", "a") as f:
        for item in content_list:
            if item in exist_data:
                msg = "Already exist "+item
                label = Label(root, text=msg)
                label.grid()
            elif not item in exist_data:
                f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

I just indented the lines after the `for item in exist_data:`

Comment: Do you know how can I change this code, that it creates excel file when it's launched for the first time and then just add new row in the file? At the moment it's creating new row in .txt. Should I import xlsxwriter ?

Comment: @JuliusC poenpyxl is what I use and it works just fine for all my excel needs.